# Qt visual studio (2010) plugin not working?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

I'd like to use Qt inside the visual studio IDE, however whenever I create a new project and select the Qt template an error pops up:

> Cannot find 'file:///D:/programs_on_d//Nokia/Qt4VSAddin/wizards/HTML/1033/default.html'. Make sure the path or Internet address is correct.

Yet when I browse to D:\progams_on_d\Nokia\Qt4VSAddin\wizards\Qt4GuiProject\html\1033, I do see the default.htm just there..

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: Just to be sure, you do realize those are two different paths?

Comment: They are? - how come? - I just did the standard installation for qt visual studio plugin?

Comment: No, you say it cannot find a file at one path, but then say you found it just fine at another path. Is that on purpose? Are you saying that the second path is what it should have been all along?

Comment: @Bart - Well yes, the second path is the correct path.. Well something else is weird about the install: using the uninstall tool for this (from windows add/remove programs) gives errors too about not being able to find the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well seems to be depending on the phase of the moon - the problem just disappeared some time later. (Without any update occuring)